# json encode and append to current form submission request laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel. I have a form with many input fields such as first name,lastname,address etc.

I want to store address data in json format since address can have address
1,adderss2,city etc so I want to store as json

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->all();
   dd($data);

}
```

it gives following result on dd($data);

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "GEBkMtY6Plwt7OMYCH41QRh7S29XdgEniExNm4z6"
  "field_855" => "john"
  "field_856" => "doe"
  "fields" => array:2 [▼
    "field_857" => array:6 [▼
      "add1" => "Avenida Eva Perón"
      "add" => "aa"
      "c" => "CJN"
      "state" => "NW"
      "p" => "23"
      "country" => "CDE"
    ]
    "field_858" => array:6 [▼
      "addressone" => "PO Box 23"
      "address2" => "dd"
      "city" => "NEWCASTLE UNIVERSITY"
      "state" => "NSW"
      "postcode" => "223"
      "country" => "ABC"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to convert the data of $request->fields into json
as `"field_857"=>[{'add1':aAvenida Eva Perón',add:'aa',c:'CJN','state':'NWW','postcode':'233','country':'ABC'}]`
same for field field_858 as well.

so final array I want is like this:

```
dd($data);


array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "GEBkMtY6Plwt7OMYCH41QRh7S29XdgEniExNm4z6"
  "form_secret_token" => "T5yb8UZqIh8znSKbgTI32kNaAjsKlk4G"
  "itoken" => "Ju4qFduCNk"
  "field_855" => "john"
  "field_856" => "doe"
  "address" => "PO Box 23, NEWCASTLE UNIVERSITY NSW 2308"
  "fields" => array:2 [▶]
  "field_857" => "[{'add1':aAvenida Eva Perón',add:'aa',c:'CJN','state':'NWW','postcode':'233','country':'ABC'}]`"
  "field_858" => "[{'addressone':PO Box 23',address2:'dd',city:'NEWCASTLE UNIVERSITY','state':'NWW','postcode':'233','country':'ABC'}]`
]
```

I used array_keys() and array_values() to get keys and values of $request->field and assign to $data, I got error:illegal offset type

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can convert the fields to json and push that to your collection:

```php
$data = $request->all();

    $result = json_encode($data->fields);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    // return $result;
    foreach($result as $key=>$r){
        $newField = [
            $key => $r
        ];
        $data[$key] = $r;
    }
    // dd($request['field_857']->add1);
    // dd($request->field_857->add1);
    dd($data);
```